# How to unit test a method that simply starts a thread with jUnit?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, junit

As in the title, I want to test a method like this:

```
public void startThread()
{
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            myLongProcess();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

EDIT:
Judging by comments I guess it is not very common to test if a thread starts or not. So I've to adjust the question... if my requirement is 100% code coverage do I need to test if that thread starts or not? If so do I really need an external framework?

Comment: I think this would be useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code

Comment: i posted my solution here: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39525700/3016686)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done elegantly with [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito). Assuming the class is named `ThreadLauncher` you can ensure the `startThread()` method resulted in a call of `myLongProcess()` with:

```
public void testStart() throws Exception {
    // creates a decorator spying on the method calls of the real instance
    ThreadLauncher launcher = Mockito.spy(new ThreadLauncher());

    launcher.startThread();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    // verifies the myLongProcess() method was called
    Mockito.verify(launcher).myLongProcess();
}
```

Comment: I would consider mocking or spying the class under test a bad practice. Instead, verify what `myLongProcess` does. It must DO something, verify it. If it is calling for other class, Mock that class to verify the call.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he wants to test if the `startThread()` method does it's job of starting a thread. He doesn't ask how to test the result of `myLongProcess()`, I assume he already knowns how to do this.

Comment: If you aim at 100% coverage you will have to execute the `startThread()` method in your tests. You can do this as I suggested, or by checking the result of the execution of `myLongProcess()` if you don't want to import Mockito in your project. The difficulty will be to wait until the method completes to check the result.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` might cause other tests in the suite to be flaky and fail unexplicably

Comment: @AmitDash How? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you need 100% coverage, you will need to call `startThread` which will kick off a thread. I recommend doing some sort of verification that the thread was stared (by verifying that something in `myLongProcess` is happening, then clean up the thread. Then you would probably do the remainder of the testing for `myLongProcess` by invoking that method directly from your unit test.