# Logging with each loop iteration and thread-sleep is bad-practice?

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube, thread-sleep

I want to log progress of some method in a specific time interval (avoiding logs overflow). I made this:

```
while (!x.isFinished()) {
     LOG.info("some progress: {}", x.getStatus());
     Thread.sleep(5000); 
}
```

As far as sonar tells it's bad practice to use `Thread.sleep(n)` and flag it as critical, I'm looking for better, proper way to make it. Is there something what I can improve?

The message is:

> Using Thread.sleep in a test is just generally a bad idea. It creates
>   brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment
>   ("Passes on my machine!") or load. Don't rely on timing

Edit: 
This is not a duplicate, it's not a test. I want to log the time during working cycle each x interval.

Edit 2 (clarification according to @Wolf S answer): 
Thanks for reply. It is used in multiple place, I want to know each time which place is it. It's examplary code. What is more, it gives me some knowledge how much time it needs to finish during it's life and help diagnostics.

I just want to know if there is maybe some strict way to do it or just ignore sonar.

Comment: What does sonarqube specifically say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Thread.sleep in Unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283334/how-to-avoid-thread-sleep-in-unit-tests)

Comment: So your real question should be "why does Sonarqube think this is a test, when it isn't?"

Comment: That's certainly _my_ question @Michael. OP, what's the path to the file with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not a test then there is no problem in your code. (There might be depending on the rest of the code but generally speaking using Thread.sleep is not automatically a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

Make your method (or object 'x') log its progress by itself.

Or make it call some callback method regularly to report progress which you can use to inject logging output (or updating a progress bar or whatever you want).